# Rpubs upload error in a script that renders appropriately in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, flexdashboard

I have a script which used to upload without any errors. It renders without any flaws in rStudio but now when I try to upload it I receive this message:

Error in rawToChar(response$headers) : argument 'x' must be a raw vector
Calls:  ... http ->  -> grep -> parse_headers -> rawToChar
Execution halted

My script is used for tracking Coronavirus Cases in a 2 million people state capital in Brazil, used by the Secretary of Health for communicating with Hospitals, please if someone could help me would be very important. Thanks!

Comment: PS: already tried options(rpubs.upload.method = "internal")

Comment: Just to clarify, you did the `options(rpubs.upload.method = "internal")` in the .Rprofile, correct? Sounds like possible network issue with authorization to the data.